# Increase upload size in phpmyadmin vagrant

Tags: phpmyadmin, vagrant

Hi I am running my server on vagrant with a r8 lamp https://github.com/r8/vagrant-lamp

I am trying to increase the size of my uploads in phpmyadmin its currently at (Max: 2,048 KiB).

I have tried editing the php.ini.erb files but no luck with this I also tried restarting my server and again no luck! :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this would apply for phpMyAdmin but I was having the same issue with a local Wordpress site. To solve it, after changing the values on the php.ini.erb files, I added these lines to the .htaccess

`php_value upload_max_filesize 20M

php_value post_max_size 20M

php_value max_execution_time 200

php_value max_input_time 200`